# Why NSManagedObject Subclass can't use class_copyMethodList find dynamic generated method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I create a NSManagedObject Subclass `Employee`,it has a property  `name`according the EntityDescription in `xcdatamodel`file. And in the .m file, the code modify it using `@dynamic` like this:

```
@interface Employee (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end   


@implementation Employee (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic name;

@end
```

According to the Apple's Document:

> Core Data dynamically generates efficient public and primitive get and set attribute accessor methods and relationship accessor methods for properties that are defined in the entity of a managed object’s corresponding managed object model. Therefore, you typically don’t need to write custom accessor methods for modeled properties.

According this, I think the CoreData Framework will create two method named `name` and `setName:`in the runtime. So I use such code to verify my thinking.

```
Employee *object = [NSEntityDescription   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
object.name = @"1";
[[self class] showInstanceMethod:[Employee class]];

+ (void)showInstanceMethod:(Class)class {
unsigned int outCount;
//..show InstanceMethodList
Method *methodsList = class_copyMethodList(class, &outCount);
for (int i = 0; i < outCount; i ++) {
    SEL sel = method_getName(*methodsList);
    NSString *methodName = NSStringFromSelector(sel);
    NSLog(@"\nmethodName:%@\n", methodName);
    methodsList++;
}
}
```

I'm sad it didn't log any method name like `name` or `setName:`.But I use this code `object.name = @"1";` and didn't have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say "dynamically" they really do mean it - the dynamic implementation seems to be provided only as and when the selector is called (directly or via `valueForKey:`).  You can see this happening if you override `resolveInstanceMethod:` in your `Employee` class.  Call the super implementation and log the selector name and return value.  Presumably the method will be listed by `class_copyMethodList` at this point, though I've never checked.